# Creating Multiple Menu at a time

Tags: menu

I have shopping cart components that have multiple categories (about 20–30 links) and I would like to create a menu in Joomla that links to all categories individually. Is there a way to batch-create multiple menu links at a time instead of adding them one by one? Any recommended plugin or module we can use to do so?

Comment: What 3rd party shopping cart are you using? It might help narrow down the potential answers to be more specific to your circumstances.

Comment: I'm using eshop. The default category module is using ajax to process the products entries on page but it won't update the URL link, this is why I'm planning to use vertical menu by offljan to create the module with its categories. Any suggestions?

Comment: What Joomla version do you use? Please add it as tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [mass content extensions in the Joomla Extension Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/mass-content) such as the free OSContent component but I am not sure which of these will create menu options for third party extensions.